# Illegal State Exception on Media Recorder

Tags: android, illegalstateexception, android-mediarecorder

I want to use Media Recorder to record and save an audio file to the `sd card`. The debugger has shown that the line `recorder.start()` raises an `IllegalStateException`. The code is taken from the android dev website and the only change is to the file name and path.

When I reach the error in the debugging menu, I am shown the `View` class which says:

Source not found.
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file View.class.
You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached Source below:

canRecord is a `boolean` set initially to true, which dictates which method is called in an `onClick` function. That functionality is working.

```
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private void record(){

    SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String audio_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/resources/resources/WI1/";
    String fileName = username +"-"+ timeStampFormat.format(new Date())+".mp4"; 
    audio_button.setText("Recording");

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audio_path+fileName);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't record audio at this time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    canRecord = false;
    recorder.start();
} // record
```

This is the stop recording function, although it has never reached this point.

```
private void stopRecording(){
    audio_button.setText("Attach Audio");
    recorder.stop();
    recorder.release();
}
```

Finally, I have added the following permissions to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is problem in filename you are giving to the recorder.Try this:

```
String audio_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/resources/resources/WI1/";
    String fileName = audiopath+"-"+ timeStampFormat.format(new Date())+".mp4";
```

May it helps..

Answer (score 1):

I am using libgdx(multiplatform open source game engine) and i had a similar problem when i was trying to use androids code instead of the libgdx code for recording.Turned out i needed to dispose of my libgdx recorder code or just delete it all.So perhaps you have another recorder interfering somewhere